# transparent header fullPage.js --> slide background visible

Tags: css, background, header, background-image, fullpage.js

is there a way to use a transparent header using fullPage.js, so I can still see the background-image from the section/slide fullscreen?

Thanks!

Comment: If you style it that way in your css there is...?

Comment: there is still a white border on top of the background.

Comment: can you provide a link? I'm guessing this is just a margin or padded added somewhere in the css you can easely overwrite.

Comment: looks like this:
jsfiddle.net/6SQhb/7/

Answer (score 0):

The white border comes from your configuration of the fullpage-plugin. You call a 50px padding on the slider, which results in a 50px white border on the top of your page. To work around this:

```
.slide { padding: 50px;}
```

This will give the same padding, but not on your wrapper element, but on the slide element. I updated your fiddle, you can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6SQhb/170/).